# How to display the contents of a list of objects?

Tags: c#

I'm new to this so the simpler, the better. I created a class that holds details of an item such as the item name, price and description. I created a constructor so that I could initialize the object upon creation.

```
class Item
{
    string itemName;
    double price;
    string description;

    public Item(string itemName, double price, string description)
    {
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

In the main class, I created a `List` of objects and two objects of that class. Then I added both objects in the `List`. How can I display each object and it's values? I tried to use foreach but I can't figure out how.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Item item1 = new Item("Ball", 9.99, "This is a ball");
    Item item2 = new Item("Toy Car", 20.00, "This is a toy car");
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

    items.Add(item1);
    items.Add(item2);

    foreach (Item s in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Either override `ToString`, or make your properties public and change your console.writeline to `Console.WriteLine("Price: " + s.price + ", Description: " + s.description + ", name: " + s.itemName);`

Comment: I agree with everything up to the "or". after that it's all violations of OO principles. If you need several output formats write `Item` methods for those. A class should be formatting it's own output. Who writes the restaurant's menu, the restaurant or the customer? Finally, use string.Format. Like so `string.Format("Price : {0:C}  Description : {1}", this.price, this.description);` Easier, cleaner, less error prone. BTW,  ":C" means to output in a money format.

Answer (score 4):

Something like that for public fields:

```
foreach (Item s in items)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", s.itemName, s.price, s.description);
}
```

Or you can override ToString() method:

```
class Item 
{
  /// your code

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", itemName, price, description);
    // or in C# 6 in Visual Studio 2015:
    // return $"{itemName} {price} {description}";
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `ToString` method for this purpose like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
     return string.Format("itemName = {0} , price = {1} , description = {2}", itemName, price, description);
}
```

Or even better with string interpolation like this (c# 6):

```
public override string ToString()
{
     return $"itemName = {itemName} , price = {price} , description = {description}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just override `ToString` to get the string output you need.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", itemName, price, description);
}
```